# Matching the Elegance and Simplicity of Confirm() with JQuery UI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, modal-dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

All,

I have a bunch of places in code where I need to have the user confirm that they want to delete some data before I execute my AJAX delete method. Easy and very common.

I am using JS confirm() for this currently.

I have spent some time researching how to use JQuery dialog in place of the Javascript confirm() method in order to get the style freedom afforded by JQuery UI.

Is there an easy and elegant way to implement JQuery UI dialog so I can replace my confirm() calls? I like the fact that the confirm() method returns right away so I know what to do next and I already have the values I need for the AJAX callback all in the same scope, etc. VS. JQuery UI dialog where it seems that a callback function needs to be set up, etc.

Here is what I have

```
$(document).on('click', '.icon.delete.counselor', function() {

    var result =  confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this counselor?');

    if (result) {

        var divId = $(this).attr("data-attr-divid");
        var recordId = $(this).attr("data-attr-id");
        var queryStr = "counselorId=" + recordId + "&newClubId=" + @Model.NewClub_Id;
        $("#" + divId).fadeOut(300, function() { $("#" + divId).remove(); });

        //ToDo: Call AJAX method to delete sponsor from DB
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/NewClubOpeningTool/DeleteCounselor',
            data: queryStr,
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: OnBegin,
            success: OnCounselorDeleteSuccess,
            failure: OnFailure,
            timeout: 5000
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: I have a plugin for jQuery UI which does this (among other things): https://bitbucket.org/MostThingsWeb/dialogwrapper/. I haven't tested it in a while but it should still work.

Comment: See for example: https://bitbucket.org/MostThingsWeb/dialogwrapper/wiki/Home#!simple-dialog-with-buttons

Comment: The basic idea is that you display a modal dialog, and bind the AJAX code to the `OK` button.

Comment: @ChrisLaplante Thanks for creating that plugin however it will need to be updated to be compatible with IE 11: "Unable to get property 'resize' of undefined or null reference.

Comment: @Slinky - I'll try to get it fixed this weekend. If you could create an issue on BitBucket with your config details I'd appreciate it, otherwise I can investigate it later.

Comment: @ChrisLaplante OK done